# How do I reset a WD Elements external hard drive to factory format?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I own a WD Elements 3TB external hard drive (WDBAAU0030HBK-01) which I disassembled and converted into an internal SATA drive. When I did that I partitioned the drive after installing it in my machine.

Now I want to use it as an external drive again so I put it back into the enclosure. However, I can't do anything with it anymore. Formatting works with neither Windows nor Linux tools.

**Using Windows Disk Management:** I am prompted to create a partition table. Once I agree to do that it tells me that the device is write-protected.

**Using Linux:** Plugging the device into a Linux machine gives lots of errors on `dmesg`:

```
[ 1351.123500] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Unhandled sense code
[ 1351.123503] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh]  
[ 1351.123505] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1351.123508] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh]  
[ 1351.123509] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 1351.123512] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh]  
[ 1351.123516] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 1351.123519] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] CDB: 
[ 1351.123520] Read(16): 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
```

When running GParted it reports:

```
Input/output error during read on /dev/sdh
```

and fails with that same error when trying to create a partition table.

My guess is that the WD SATA/USB converter that is part of the external hard drive enclosure requires the drive to be formatted in a certain way. Otherwise it will not accept commands.

How can I make this drive work in the external enclosure again?

Comment: Given the cost of a generic usb enclosure, I would just bin that one and buy one that doesn't have these measures

Comment: You sure you didn't rook the USB adapter while disassembling the enclosure?

Comment: @techie007 Might be possible but I think it's unlikely. I'm thinking the drive was in a special format because I couldn't read it when I hooked it up via SATA first even though it was working fine via USB.

Comment: @Paul Yes, that would be the pragmatic measure which I will probably take next if all else fails. My main motivation is understanding what WD does to the drive and not so much saving those few bucks on a new enclosure.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would make a backup of everything on the drive that you don't want to lose. After you've backed up your drive, you'll want to try [Western Digitals Formatting Program](http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=304&sid=34&lang=en) to reformat the drive.

If that doesn't work, you will have to do what is called a 'zero write' or 'low-level formatting', and then reformat the drive using the above software.

> A zero write takes an extremely long time especially on a 3TB drive (try 12 hours for 350GB! I recommend trying to format it via WD's software **FIRST**; it writes over your entire hard drive with zeroes, effectively deleting ALL the information on the drive. **This will delete ALL formatting and ALL data on the drive.**

There are many tools to do this (note that with a 3TB drive it could take weeks), however definitely try using Western Digitals' program to do this first before trying others (then you can blame them if something happens :P )
[Western Digital's Data LifeGuard](http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&sid=3&lang=en)

### Use Only As A Last Resort:

If you have a HDD:

I recommend [Darik's Boot And Nuke (DBAN)](http://www.dban.org/download)

Follow the instructions to install this onto either a cd-r or a pen-drive; remove any usb, cd's, or drives you don't want to be overwritten, then restart your computer with the pen drive/cd-r in it (do this on a computer you will not use for a while).

**WARNING! DO NOT USE DBAN ON A SOLID STATE DRIVE. IT WILL NOT WRITE PROPERLY/COMPLETELY, AND COULD DAMAGE THE DRIVE.**

If you have a SSD (Solid State Drive):

I have never used this software, and probably will not be able to help you with it, however it was recommended to me, so I felt I should include it.

[LowLevelFormat](http://www.lowlevelformat.info/zero-filling.aspx) - Does exactly what you need, and provides good information on their website

I hope for your sake that you do not have to do a zero write, but on the bright side it might increase your drive speed too. Good luck, and let me know how it goes!

Comment: I would think only the first few kilobytes would technically need to be zeroed (if time is a concern). The rest should be over-written by the new filesystem and partitions, right?

Comment: It would definitely work on a HDD, but I'm not entirely sure if that's the case with SSD's though as they don't necessarily save files in order, especially if there's bad sectors involved